# NODATA Value for view-shed Anlysis in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis, raster, arcmap

I am going to do a viewshed Analysis. I have dsm (digital surface model) data and a point data.

Since I am sure the dsm data have values, it gives back Empty field!

would you please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the entire raster output NoData? What are the projections of your inputs (both DSM and point)?

Comment: I have a big area which covered by more than 20 DSM grid file, in the same Projection sys as the point is.

Comment: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
(DAO.Recordset) No current record.
ERROR 010004: All cells in Raster 2080h have the NODATA value. Stop execution.
No valid Observation points present.  Point 1 with coordinates 0.000, 2.918 is NODATA.
ERROR 010067: Error in executing grid expression.
Failed to execute (Viewshed).

Comment: Is your point in the same area as the DSM (e.g. on the surface) or some distance away?

Comment: yes, it is! I am a bit confused. there are 20 ASC file as dsm. should I convert them to raster?! and should they be as one raster!   another problem is probably with the point layer. I created this layer myself. and I did not assign any Z value to that points, because I do not know how to get the altitude of that point from the raster!

Comment: Not sure, but try converting it to a single raster. If the point value does not have a Z value of its own, it should automatically take the elevation from the surface beneath it, so I do not think that is your problem :)

Comment: I tried it works. I found the problem. dsm is in a grid form and just can be applied for that grid which the point is in! so what should I do with other rasters! how I can make a raster out of many rasters?

Comment: Look at the mosaic tool.